# HP 8350B Sweep Oscillator connection

Tags: oscillator

How to connect HP 8350B Sweep Oscillator connection to a Oscilloscope or to a device?

TIA

Comment: Note that this device is designed to generate signals at microwave frequencies (up to 40 GHz). Thus its output will be difficult to display on most oscilloscopes available to hobbyists. In any case, you need a cable with a connector that matches that on the unit and it should be terminated in a 50 ohm load for proper operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer 
But I tried with low frequencies within the range of the oscilloscope but saw noises. 
Couldn’t identify what kind of waveform it generates

Comment: I also have a RF plugin Hp 83592B attached to it but don’t know how to generate sine wave or combine these two